# How to dynamically add a column template kendo ui grid column

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I need to dynamically add templates to kendo ui grid columns based off of user input.

Can I add a template to a grid column after the grid has been created?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you must either wait to render the grid *after* user input or destroy and rebuild it each time the user input changes. [Here](http://jsbin.com/zutidexubi/1/edit?html,js,output) is a working example. Input a string like `<i>#=name#</i>` in the Name Template textbox and you'll see how the template can be affected. Come up with more complex templates as you see fit.

*Html*

```
<body>
  <div id="choices">
    <label>Name Template</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: nameTemplate"/>
    <label>Age Template</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: ageTemplate"/>
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: buildGrid">Build Grid</button>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div id="grid"></div>
</body>
```

*Script*

```
$(function() {
  var grid = {};

  var columns = [
    { field: 'name' },
    { field: 'age' }
  ];

  var vm = kendo.observable({
    nameTemplate: '',
    ageTemplate: '',
    buildGrid: buildGrid
  });

  function buildGrid() {    
    if (vm.nameTemplate !== '') {
      columns[0].template = vm.nameTemplate;
    }

    if (vm.ageTemplate !== '') {
      columns[1].template = vm.ageTemplate;
    }

    grid = $('#grid').kendoGrid({
      columns: columns,
      dataSource: [
        { name: 'Jacob', age: 42 }, 
        { name: 'Cindy', age: 28 }
      ]
    }).data('kendoGrid');
  }

  kendo.bind('#choices', vm);
});
```